# How to iterate over an array list of beans in a JSP using struts2 tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

My JSP receives an `ArrayList` of beans from a Struts2 action.

I want to iterate over them and print every bean and its properties per line.

How can I do this using Struts2 tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`<s:iterator>`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/iterator.html) tag.

```
<s:iterator value="beans">
     <p>Property foo: <s:property name="foo" /></p>
     <p>Property bar: <s:property name="bar" /></p>
</s:iterator>
```

An overview of all tags can be found in their own documentation: [tag reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/tag-reference.html). Bookmark it.

Comment: what if each of the arraylist's element is an object whose values I want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Using JSTL:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.property}" />
</c:forEach>
```

You will have to add JSTL to the classpath, because it isn't shipped with Struts, but it shoul work. Of course, using struts' own tag (as shown by BalusC) is a better option.

Comment: @lakshmanan I don't think there is a problem to use JSTL with struts2

Answer (score 1):

To do this with struts2 you need iterator:

```
<s:iterator value="collection">
Describe object
</s:iterator>
```

But I suggest to use displaytag: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/
With only 1 row it describes all the bean and you can do also sorting and export.
Here an example of use:

```
<display:table name="collection" />
```

and it generate a table, a thead and the tbody.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13531199/IteratorOverObjects.zip.html) is a working example(Netbeans 6.9 project) illustrating how to iterate over an array or list of objects.

Also, how to submit the form such that the list of objects gets re-created on submission.

Simply resolve the references and get going.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in my basic application.

Here **searchForm is bean** and **ArrayList is results**

```
<logic:present name="searchForm" property="results">
    <bean:size id="size" name="searchForm" property="results"/>
   <logic:greaterThan name="size" value="0">
       <logic:iterate id="res" name="searchForm" property="results">
         <p>
         <bean:write name="res" property="firstname" />
         <bean:write name="res" property="lastname" />
         </p>
       </logic:iterate>
   </logic:greaterThan>
</logic:present>
```